# Countless (defunct?) SSH processes -how do stop it from happening?

Tags: ssh, debian, malicious

My vServer hoster threatens to cancel our contract if I don't stop creating thousands (9000 to be precise) of SSH processes. I don't know if they made the processes defunct or if they were like this when they found them. They sent me a document containing thousands of lines like

```
sshd     19716  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Jan25   0:00 [sshd] <defunct>
sshd     19739  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Jan25   0:00 [sshd] <defunct>
sshd     19753  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Jan25   0:00 [sshd] <defunct>
sshd     19776  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Jan26   0:00 [sshd] <defunct>
```

I have no idea how that happened and I would like to know a solution so I won't get cancelled before turning the server on again!
The only thing I can think of is that I often connected to the server with an extremely unstable connection. Could that lead to the creation of thousand processes over weeks and months?
Could my server be hacked? I don't use fail2ban (nor do I know how) but I do use a keyfile.

The server runs on Debian with Apache & a Tomcat.

Comment: Can you provide a list of connections with an hour:min instead of a date (like Jan 25 in your list)? That helps to see the new connections rate. And also provide us with how many connections do you have on a single day, or per day on 2 or 3 days.

Comment: The list snippet I posted was provided by my hoster and my vServer is currently turned off, so I guess the information is lost.

Comment: You only have this 4 items count? If so, you just have to take precautions.

Comment: Here is the whole list they sent me: https://ncry.pt/p/W4Bn#TPmBAWNIedVQ3KnnV-omrz4xx5ZG8b__1LqaBaIL3tw

Answer (score 3):

Take precautions. The options are from the best to the worst.

### Option 1: use fail2ban to limit fails

Install fail2ban. That's your best option, as it blocks whoever tries to connect with invalid credentials after some attempts.

### Option 2: limit failed attempts in iptables

Setup iptables to limit the new connections to SSH.

```
# Create new SSHSCAN chain
iptables -N SSHSCAN
# Send new SSH attempts to SSHSCAN chain.
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j SSHSCAN
# Identify a recent-match list, based on the source address
iptables -A SSHSCAN -m recent --set --name SSH --rsource
# Log and drop if there are more than 5 
iptables -A SSHSCAN -m recent --update --seconds 10 --hitcount 5 --name SSH --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "Anti SSH-Bruteforce: " --log-level 6
iptables -A SSHSCAN -m recent --update --seconds 10 --hitcount 5 --name SSH --rsource -j DROP
```

Check [info](http://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x2682.html#RECENTMATCH) for more info about recent match in iptables.

Thank you to @gaurav-pundir for the commands.

### Option 3: limit the source of the SSH accesses

Optin 3 is setup firewall so that you ensure that only you can access: block SSH so that only you your IP (if it's static) or your providers network can access. The network block option is not pratical and you probably don't have the a fixed IP available. Even if it's the worst, for dynamic addresses, you may consider to implement it, even if you have one of the other options implemented.

### Problem source

**Edit**: from your recent list it seems to me that your unstable connection is leaving zombie connections. This won't fix your problem, but would not make any harm, anyway.

Comment: command for option 2 "iptables -N SSHSCAN  ; iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j SSHSCAN ; iptables -A SSHSCAN -m recent --set --name SSH --rsource ; iptables -A SSHSCAN -m recent --update --seconds 10 --hitcount 5 --name SSH --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "Anti SSH-Bruteforce: " --log-level 6 ; iptables -A SSHSCAN -m recent --update --seconds 10 --hitcount 5 --name SSH --rsource -j DROP"

Comment: fail2ban sounds like the smartest idea and it seems to be best practice anyways. I am not even sure I got hacked though!